# Error while finding java version on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I recently messed up badly in eclipse, so was doing some digging to update/fix jdk.

While executing `java -version` to find Java version on my Ubuntu 12.04, i get the below error and even on following `sudo apt-get install <selected package>` for any of the packages, the problem persists!!

> The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
>   *
>   default-jre
>   * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
>   *
>   openjdk-6-jre-headless
>   * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
>   *
>   openjdk-7-jre-headless
>  Try: sudo apt-get install

**Can any one tell me what does this mean** and what is needed to be done to correct it, couldn't find much on internet about this!!

**PS :** i have executed `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless` and it tells that :

> openjdk-7-jre-headless is already the newest version.
>  0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

so jre is there somewhere....what's the bug then?????

**Why asking this question because** eclipse is throwing this error and i need to fix jre/jdk to run it but i am total noob in this!!

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
>   /usr/lib/eclipse/jre/bin/java
>  java in your current PATH

[i was not able to login to my ubuntu account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216973/not-able-to-log-in-to-my-associated-account)  
so 
 [asked the same question on SO first!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264927/error-while-finding-java-version-on-ubuntu#21264960)

Comment: Eclipse is trying to find Java in another path. You need to tell us how you installed eclipse.

Comment: @Braiam : i just installed it using the `software-center`....it installed directly from there.

Comment: Could you append the results of `locate java | grep bin/java`?

Answer (score 0):

try running sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jre-headless

Comment: tried...this is what i got => `Setting up openjdk-7-jre-headless (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...`

`Loading classlist failed: No such file or directory`
`ignoring dump failure`

`Loading classlist failed: No such file or directory`
ignoring dump failure

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is to do the following.

Add Java 8 repository and get this version installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

check what is the current version on your system (which versions you have and which is a main one):

```
java -version
```

if you need a specific one, for example, Java 8 just installed, run:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose a version which you would like to use.

Let me know if this worked for you :)